# How do I translate the radio selection buttons?

Tags: python, html, django

I am using the i18n language change, the issue is that in several of my forms I was able to do the translation, the problem is that when there is a radio button in forms.py I don't know how to translate the options

> html

```
<div class="mb-3">
  <label class="form-label d-block mb-3">{% trans "Country" %}:</label>
  <div class="custom-radio form-check form-check-inline">
     {{ form.pais }}
  </div>
</div>
```

> forms.py

```
PAIS = (
   ('United States', 'United States'),
   ('Canada', 'Canada'),
   ('Other', 'Other'),
) 
class ClientesForm(forms.ModelForm):

   pais = forms.ChoiceField(
       choices=PAIS,
       widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class':'custom-radio-list'}),

   )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with the [**`gettext_lazy(…)`** function <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy) to work with lazy translatable strings:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

PAIS = (
   ('United States', _('United States')),
   ('Canada', _('Canada')),
   ('Other', _('Other')),
)
```

This will add translations for `United States`, `Canada`, etc. when you make translations, and translate the text when the form is rendered.

For more information, see the [*Lazy translations* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translation).

Comment: thank you very much in fact, I did what you recommended and the words appeared in django.po, only that when I compiled the translation did not appear

Comment: You passed the list with the lazy-translated values as `choices=...` right? Not another list?

Comment: yes it works, I don't know what happened I refreshed the page again, thanks :D